# nada tiene que ver or nada no tiene que ver

Tags: gramática, negación

ReversoDiccionario gives an example of "tener que ver" as, "Nada tiene que ver nuestra amistad con tus asuntos turbios." Is this really a correct sentence or should it be, "Nada no tiene que ver nuestra amistad con tus asuntos turbios"?

Link:
https://diccionario.reverso.net/espanol-definiciones/no+tener+nada+que+ver

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RAE explains this [here](https://www.rae.es/espanol-al-dia/doble-negacion-no-vino-nadie-no-hice-nada-no-tengo-ninguna):

> Los adverbios *nunca, jamás, tampoco*, los indefinidos *nadie, nada, ninguno*, la locución *en la/mi/tu/su vida* y los grupos que contienen la palabra *ni* aparecen siempre en oraciones de sentido negativo. Si estos elementos van antepuestos al verbo, este no va acompañado del adverbio de negación *no*: ***Nunca** voy al teatro* [...]. Pero si van pospuestos al verbo, este debe ir necesariamente precedido del adverbio *no*: ***No** voy **nunca** al teatro*.  La concurrencia de esas dos «negaciones» no anula el sentido negativo del enunciado, sino que lo refuerza.

So the negative adverbs *nunca, jamás, tampoco* and the negative indefinite pronouns *nadie, nada, ninguno* require the use of the word **no** if they appear after the verb, but they do not need the word **no** if they appear before the verb. In both cases, the sentence keeps its negative meaning. The following two sentences are equivalent:

- **Nada** tiene que ver nuestra amistad con tus asuntos turbios.

and

- Nuestra amistad **no** tiene **nada** que ver con tus asuntos turbios.

Comment: Thank you so much!